# Show that there exists a prime ideal contained in $J = \{a \in R : ab = 0 \text{ for some } b\neq 0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let
$$J = \{a \in R : ab = 0 \text{ for some } b\neq 0\}$$

Show that there exists a prime ideal contained in $J$.

Attempt:

I can see that this set contains all zero divisors along with zero itself.

Considering the contrapositive of the definition of prime ideal we need to prove that if $x,y \in J^c \implies xy \in J^c$.

Proof: Assume if possible $xy \in J$ then there exists a non-zero element $z$ such that $(xy)z = 0$, using the associative property of multiplication $x(yz) = 0$, now $yz \neq 0$ as $y \in J^c$ hence we can conclude $x(yz) \neq 0$. Which gives us the required contradiction.

There are two questions I want to ask:

Does the proof furnished above answer the question asked ?

But what I don't understand is why is the phrase "there exists a prime ideal contained in J" being used, why not use show that "J is the prime ideal"?

Comment: You did not prove that $J$ is an ideal, I also think that this is generally not the case. In the ring $\mathbb{R}[X, Y]/(XY)$ for example, $X, Y \in J$ but $X + Y \not\in J$.

Comment: @Bib-lost Ok, but is the general idea of the proof correct ?

Comment: Your proof of $xy \in J \Rightarrow x \in J$ or $y \in J$ is correct, but does not answer the original question, as $J$ is not an ideal.

Answer (score 4):

$J$ is the set of zero divisors. You argued correctly that $x, y \in J^c \Rightarrow xy \in J^c$. However, $J$ is not an ideal in general, as my answer in the comments shows.

The question now is to show that $J$ contains a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, i.e. an *ideal* $\mathfrak{p}$ consisting of only zero divisors ($\mathfrak{p} \subseteq J$) and such that $x, y \in \mathfrak{p}^c \Rightarrow xy \in \mathfrak{p}^c$. It's not clear from what you said yet that such an ideal exists.

Let's consider the set $\Omega$ of ideals contained in $J$. Clearly $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ as $\lbrace 0 \rbrace \in \Omega$. Using Zorn's Lemma one sees that this set $\Omega$ contains a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Use the part of the argument you already had to show that $\mathfrak{m}$ is a prime ideal, and then you're done.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the set of zero-divisors, in general, is not even an ideal.

*Counter-example*: in $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$ the zero-divisors are the congruence classes of $2, 3, 4$. These are not an ideal, since $2+3=5$, for instance, is a unit in $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$.

**Hint:**

Consider the set of ideals contained in $J$, ordered by inclusion, and apply Zorn's lemma to obtain an ideal contained in $J$ which is maximal w.r.t. inclusion. Then show this ideal is prime .